# How to Install Ubuntu 14.04 on Specific Partition?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 14.04

I am Installing **Ubuntu 14.04** From Bootable DVD.

After Choosing `Something Else` Option, It Doesn't Show My Current Partition Table And It Is Necessary To Create New Partition Table.

[image: Something Else]

[image: New Partition Table]

So, How To Use My Current Partition Table To Install Ubuntu On Specific Drive **Without Losing Data of other Partitions**?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Not Detecting Windows XP so-that I Can't Install Ubuntu 14.04 Alongside It.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have Total 5 Partition In Which 2 Are Primary And 3 Are Logical.**

Therefore, I Deleted My Second Primary Partition And Create Logical Instead. Now, There is only **1 Primary and 4 Logical Partitions.**

Now, Ubuntu 14.04 Installation `Shows My Current Partition Table`. And Problem is Solved!
(Now It Also Detects Windows XP).

This Answer Should Helpful To Others Which are Facing Similar Problem.