# Installing Ubuntu asked to format whole hard disk

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I recently tried to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Laptop, but it kept showing only 1 HDD partition (whole HDD as 1 partition) and kept asking to format it completely to install Ubuntu.
I already have 3 partitions, C was Windows, D was a empty NTFS 80GB free space partition, E was my personal data partition.
Ubuntu kept showing only 1 single HDD before installing it, it kept asking to completely erase data to install itself.

Is there any way to avoid it, save my data from deletion and install Ubuntu on one partition only, not affecting the data saved on other partition?

I remember I installed Linux Mint years ago, and I saved all my data, and installed on new partition.
This time it just seems to fail.

Edited part,

Let me start with few details first, I used Yumi (1.9.9.9B version) software to make a bootable ubuntu (ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64).

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y510p laptop, which came with Windoez 8 presinstalled OS, i took out the internal hdd, put it in enclosure formated it completely to install Windoez 7. Now i have Windoez 7 intalled, and wanted to put Ubuntu.

Now i am trying to install Ubuntu from usb, will take screen shots to tell what happens.

Comment: At which point exactly does the Ubuntu installer fail to do what you expect? Can you describe the steps you're taking and what goes wrong? It would also help to see a picture or [listing of your current partition scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458799/2461638). Please [edit] your question, if you want to include additional info.

Comment: Did you install Windows 7 in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. If in BIOS mode, that is the issue as it does not correctly convert drive from gpt partitioning to MBR partitioning. Post this from terminal in Live installer. sudo parted -l and sudo fdisk -lu

Comment: Here is the screen shot of where i got stuck while installing ubuntu. 1- http://i1089.photobucket.com/albums/i347/Pushendu/DSC_6863_zpsa6ea0608.jpg      2- http://i1089.photobucket.com/albums/i347/Pushendu/DSC_6870_zpsaa15cdce.jpg   After step 2, i have no clue, can't find partitions to install ubuntu on any specific partition.

Comment: Hi Oldfred, i took a image of boot menu too, please have a look and guide me as i have less knowledge about it.  Link - http://i1089.photobucket.com/albums/i347/Pushendu/IMG_0218_zps33d2f2fc.jpg    ty

Comment: eagerly waiting.... :p

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions/778813#778813

Comment: I faced similar [problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/452248/256099) and solution is to keep only 1 as primary partition and other should be logical

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this from Yumi?
Important Note: YUMI was intended to be used to try to run various "LIVE Linux" Operating Systems from USB. Installing Linux from the YUMI created USB Drive to a Hard Drive is not officially supported. If the installer portion of any Live Linux distro does work, consider it a bonus.
As it should work, ubuntu provides you different choices. I suggest you try out this [software](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) as it has been proven to work and let us know if the problem remains. Thank you.